# Are there two motivations for Bayesian information criteria?

Tags: prediction, model-selection, entropy, information-theory, kullback-leibler

Are there two motivations for all these Bayesian information criteria? I am only aware of the motivation of "expected out-of-sample prediction score."

Let the in-sample data be $y$ and the parameter be called $\theta$. Assume that $y\mid \theta \sim p(y \mid \theta)$ and that the prior is $p(\theta)$. Call the posterior mean $\hat{\theta}(y)$, and let the out-of-sample data be called $Y$. This closely follows the notation found [here](http://users.jyu.fi/~hemipu/itms/Spiegelhalter%20et%20al.%202002%20JRSSb%20DIC.pdf).

The "effective number of parameters" described by that paper is 
\begin{align*}
p_D &= E_{\theta \mid y}\left[ - 2 \log p(y \mid \theta) \right] + 2 \log p(y \mid \hat{\theta}(y)) \\
\end{align*}

Why isn't there being an expectation taken with respect to unobserved data $Y$ in the above expression? I thought the whole point of this class of model selection strategies was to approximate (ideally) $E_Y\left[ E_{\theta \mid y}\left[ \log p(Y \mid \theta) \right] \right]$, or more realistically 
\begin{align*}
E_Y\left[-2  \log p(Y \mid \hat{\theta}(y))  \right] &= - 2\log p(y \mid \hat{\theta}(y)) \\
&+ \underbrace{E_Y\left[  -2\log p(Y \mid \hat{\theta}(y))  \right] + 2\log p(y \mid \hat{\theta}(y))}_{\text{a better }p_D \text{?}}
\end{align*}

But clearly
$$
E_Y\left[  -2\log p(Y \mid \hat{\theta}(y))  \right] \neq E_{\theta \mid y}\left[ - 2 \log p(y \mid \theta) \right].
$$
Is that just a commonly-used approximation?

Comment: You could consider the possibility that there are more than two.

Comment: Just avoid DIC, it is a toxic measure!